# Please I really need help with that . The question is : Is $\hat{B}_1$ an unbiased estimator of $B$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

A random sample of 3 observations was obtained from this
population. Consider the following estimators of $B$ :

$\hat{B}_1 = (Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3)/3$ and $\hat{B}_2 = Y_1/6 + Y_2/3 + Y_3/2$.
Is $\hat{B}_1$ an unbiased estimator of $B$? What about $\hat{B}_2$?

and the answer to that  is:
\begin{align*}
E(\hat{B}_1)&=E((Y_1/3)+(Y_2/3)+(Y_3/3)\\
&= (1/3)E(Y_1)+(1/3)E(Y_2)+(1/3)E(Y_3)\\
&= (1/3)B + (1/3)B+ (1/3)B = B
\end{align*}
Thus, $\hat{B}_1$ is an unbiased estimator.

my question then is, what sort of property is applying here? I am not getting anything of what is being done ...if they gave me a let's say coeficient, and then a sample I could run the OLS on the sample getting the coeficient and then compare them both...but what the hell..whats going on here??

Comment: I have just set the example of B1, te other concludes that is also an estimator of b by proceeding in the same way as in b1

Comment: There are peculiarities of terminology. We have a random variable $Y$, with mean $\mu$. Then indeed both $\frac{1}{3}(Y_1+Y_2+Y_3)$ and the other one are unbiased estimators of $\mu$, since each of the two random variables has mean $\mu$. But in the post $B$ is never defined. From the notation, $B$ looks like a random variable, which makes no sense at all. Unbiasedness is a desirable property in estimators, it means the estimator is on average right. But there are several other desirable propertes, such as having as low a variance as possible. (Cont)

Comment: (Cont) The exercise is probably just to get you to practice "mean of a linear combination is linear combination of the means," and to remind you of the definition of unbiasedness.

Comment: B is meant to be beta, sorry. But still I am not getting it. why is unbiassed? becasue the denominator coincides with the mean? The observation is (Y/3)*B +(Y/6)*B + (Y/2)* B and proceeds the same way and also conludes that is an unbiased estimator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we are sampling from a population, say of people.  For each person in our sample, we measure some feature of interest, say blood cholesterol level. We are interested in estimating the mean population blood cholesterol level. Denote that mean population level by $\beta$. The purpose of our experiment is to **estimate** $\beta$.

Suppose we do the sampling $3$ times (that's a very small sample). Let random variables $Y_1, Y_2,Y_3$ be the results, that is, the blood cholesterol levels of the $3$ people.

Each act of sampling can be used to find information about the value of the population mean  $\beta$.

An **estimator** for $\beta$ is a random variable, based on sampling, designed to estimate some particular parameter, in this case $\beta$.

There are many ways one can imagine "combining" the random variables $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ to estimate $\beta$. For example, one could use $\sqrt[3]{Y_1Y_2Y_3}$, or many other things, reasonable or not.

The question asks about two specific estimators, both of the shape $a_1Y_1+a_2Y_2+a_3Y_3$, where the $a_i$ are constants.

The fundamental fact to be used is the **linearity of expectation**. In our general situation, this says
$$E(a_1Y_1+a_2Y_2+a_3Y_3)=a_1E(Y_1)+a_2E(Y_2)+a_3E(Y_3).$$

**The estimator $B_1$:** We have $a_i=\frac{1}{3}$ for all $i$. Recall that $E(Y_i)=\beta$. So by the linearity of expectation, we have 
$$E(B_1)=E\left(\frac{1}{3}Y_1+\frac{1}{3}Y_2+\frac{1}{3}Y_3\right)=\frac{1}{3}\beta+\frac{1}{3}\beta+\frac{1}{3}\beta=\beta.$$
Thus if we use $B_1$ to estimate $\gamma$, on average we will get the right value.
Thus $B_1$ is an unbiased estimator of $\beta$.

**The estimator $B_2$:** This is very similar to $B_1$, with $a_1=\frac{1}{6}$, $a_2=\frac{1}{3}$, and $a_3=\frac{1}{2}$. By the linearity of expectation, we
 have $E(B_2)=\frac{1}{6}\beta+\frac{1}{3}\beta+\frac{1}{2}\beta=\beta$.

Thus $B_2$ is also an unbiased estimator of $\beta$.

---

What the two random variables $B_1$ and $B_2$ have in common is that the "weights" $a_1,a_2,a_3$ in each case have sum equal to $1$.  In any such case we will have $E(a_1Y_1+a_2Y_2)=a_1\beta+a_2\beta+a_3\beta=(a_1+a_2+a_3)\beta=\beta$.

---

By the way, $B_1$ and $B_2$, though both unbiased, are not equally good as estimators. It turns out that $B_1$ has lower variance than $B_2$, and when we are comparing unbiased estimators, lower variance is good.

Comment: fantastic, thanks so so much, so clear now , thanks a lot :)

Comment: ok, going back to that..how do you work out the variance?

Comment: We do not know the variance of the $Y_i$. Call it $\sigma^2$. We use the fact that if random variables $Y_i$ are independent, then the variance of $\sum a_iY_i$ is $\sum a_i^2 \text{Var}Y_i$. Using that, we can calculate the variance of $B_1$ and of $B_2$ in terms of $\sigma^2$. The one for $B_1$ turns out to be smaller.